# Insert empty row in GtkGrid c

Tags: c, gtk

How to leave a empty row in GtkGrid

I want to create a gtkgrid with buttons like in example:

```
        0         1        2         3
   ------------------------------------------
0  |         |           button2           |      
   - button1 -------------------------------
1  |         |           button3           |
   -----------------------------------------
2  |         |           button4           |
   -----------------------------------------
3  |         |         |         |         |
   -----------------------------------------
4  |         |      button5      |         |
   -----------------------------------------
```

How to insert a empty row (3) in grid and this row to show as space in gui?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to accomplish a similar task and found a work-around.  I'm using GTK+3.  I just added an empty label to one of the cells in the 3rd row to cause GTK to allocate space for the row without displaying anything.

You could do something like this (I'm assuming the second `button2` was meant to be `button5`):

```
// Declare widgets.
    GtkWidget *button1 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button1");
    GtkWidget *button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button2");
    GtkWidget *button3 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button3");
    GtkWidget *button4 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button4");
    GtkWidget *button5 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button5");
    GtkWidget *space = gtk_label_new("");
    GtkWidget *buttonGrid = gtk_grid_new();

//  Attach to the grid.
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(buttonGrid),button1,0,0,1,2);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(buttonGrid),button2,1,0,3,1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(buttonGrid),button3,1,1,3,1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(buttonGrid),button4,1,2,3,1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(buttonGrid),button5,1,4,2,1);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(buttonGrid),space,2,3,1,1);
    gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(buttonGrid),TRUE);
```

This produces a layout like this: 
[image: layout produced]