# How does GTK grid container positioning works?

Tags: python, user-interface, grid, gtk, positioning

This is my code

```
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="GUi")
        self.ui()

    def ui(self):
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 1")
        button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Button 2")
        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(grid)
        grid.attach(button1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.attach(button2, 0, 3, 2, 2)
        self.show_all()

window = Window()
Gtk.main()
```

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OORG0.jpg) is my output but I have mentioned the button 2 to appear in the 3rd column and gave it row and column span of 2 but both of these are not working as expected what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert empty row in GtkGrid c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665369/insert-empty-row-in-gtkgrid-c)

Comment: Also, note that when calling this: `grid.attach(button2, 0, 3, 2, 2)`, the first integer parameter is the column. This means `button2` is not in the third column, but in the first (0-based). See [the reference](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Grid.attach.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the impression that you are try trying to place the buttons beside each other with a space between them. check out this link where it mentions grid to get a better idea of what arguments for `grid.attach(a,b,c,d,e)` are.

- (a) The child parameter is the Gtk.Widget to add.
- (b) left is the column number to attach the left side of child to.
- (c) top indicates the row number to attach the top side of child to.
- (d, e) width and height indicate the number of columns that the child will span, and the number of rows that the child will span, respectively.

https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html

you wont be able to put a space without using something like.

```
grid.set_row_spacing(20)
grid.set_column_spacing(20)
```

or maybe cell padding or button alignment. for more on that look at this link
https://athenajc.gitbooks.io/python-gtk-3-api/content/gtk-group/gtkgrid.html

keep in mind when thinking about sizing and positioning are inherited from classes. Positioning is tricky because you are can't really make a space between.